# replacing image path with regular expression

Tags: regex, expression

I have massive html code, with loooads of images, problem is, every single image has a different path, example:

`<img src="../media/2010/01/something.jpg" />`

`<img src="../media/logo.png" />`

What I wanted to do with regular expressions is, to find every image path and replace it with:

`<img src="../img/FILENAME.EXTENSION" />`

I know that it's definately possible with regular expressions ... but it's just not my cup of tea, could any1 help me please?

Cheers, Mart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not be the best solution but it might work:

```
(<img.*?src=")([^"]*?(\/[^/]*\.[^"]+))
```

and then you use capture group 1 and 3 to create the new string (depending on flavor):

```
$1../img$3
```

You can see it in action here: http://regexr.com?2v8ir

Answer (score 0):

Try [this link](http://regexr.com?2v8il)

Using this regex `<img src="[\w/\.]+"(\s|)/>` and replacing with `<img src="../img/FILENAME.EXTENSION" />`

Comment: I think OP would like to keep the original name and extension and not the hardcoded

Comment: And for that matter, even the URL of that link doesn't say anything useful: http://regexr.com/?2v8il I shouldn't need to click on an external link to see a regular expression.

Comment: @Andrew, BoltClock & Marcus: Thanks for notifying me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse html, its much better if you use an html parser instead of regex. There are quite alot of them and they do a very good work.

[Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is a good one