# Regex: Modify img src tags

Tags: php, html, regex, image

I try to replace all images in a html document with inline image (data:image).
I've a sample code which does not work:

```
function data_uri($filename) {
$mime = mime_content_type($filename);
$data = base64_encode(file_get_contents($filename));
return "data:$mime;base64,$data";
}

function img_handler($matches) { 
$image_element = $matches[1];    
$pattern = '/(src=["\'])([^"\']+)(["\'])/'; 
$image_element = preg_replace($pattern, create_function( 
$matches, 
$matches[1] . data_uri($matches[2]) . $matches[3]), 
$image_element);     
return $image_element;
}

$content = (many) different img tags
$search = '(<img\s+[^>]+>)';
$content = preg_replace_callback($search, 'img_handler', $content);
```

Could somebody check this code? Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
(...) Warning file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Filename cannot be empty (...)

That means the src url is not in the handler :(

**UPDATE 2**

```
<?php
function data_uri($filename) {
    $mime = mime_content_type($filename);
    $data = base64_encode(file_get_contents($filename));

    return "data:$mime;base64,$data";
}

function img_handler($matches) { 
$image_element = $matches[0];
$pattern = '/(src=["\'])([^"\']+)(["\'])/'; 
$image_element = preg_replace_callback($pattern, create_function( 
$matchess,
$matchess[1] . data_uri($matchess[2]) . $matchess[3]), 
$image_element); 
return $image_element;
}

$content = '<a href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/44/Googlelogoi.png/180px-Googlelogoi.png"><img class="alignnone" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/44/Googlelogoi.png/180px-Googlelogoi.png" alt="google" width="580" height="326" title="google" /></a>';
$search = '(<img\s+[^>]+>)';
$content = preg_replace_callback($search, 'img_handler', $content);

echo $content;
?>
```

I've upload this test file -> http://goo.gl/vWl9B

Comment: What does not work? What happens instead? Also, consider using a DOM parser instead. Also, it looks like you intended to use another `preg_replace_callback` instead of `preg_replace` within `img_handler`

Comment: I want to use regex (not a DOM Parser). But how could I solve this problem?

Comment: This means your regex finds the img tags but does not extract the src tag so file_get_contents gets an empty string as filename

Comment: @user1756209 my point is not that it's a matter of taste whether you use regex or a DOM parser. [regular expressions are not powerful enough to parse HTML.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) you will never get a perfect solution and choke on any odd (not even speaking of invalid) HTML. check out [this DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) for example... it's really easy to use and will work in many more cases than any possible regex solution.

Comment: Yes this is what I already know - but how could I fix this?

Comment: @user1756209, the problem might be, that both your callbacks use the variable name `$matches` and I believe within your second callback it is already evaluated on creating the function. try changing the variable name within your anonymous callback to something else.

Comment: I can't use a DOM Parser (in this project). I've changed the name -> same error!

Comment: @user1756209 please edit your question here instead of asking a new one. you still have `preg_replace` instead of `preg_replace_callback`. Why? Does it help changing it?

Comment: A DOM parser is the correct approach to solve your issue, and yet "you don't want" to use it? What good is it to ask a question if you're going to disregard the correct answer?

Comment: @m.buettner I searched many hours for a solution. But nobody could solve this problem :( I've updated the question below. You could find an example!

Comment: @maiorano84 I can't use an extra DOM library in my project (android app + wordpress plugin). It must work on different servers... and it must not 100% correct - but it should work with regex ...

Comment: [A DOM parser is built into PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: An other people says this is correct. This code is from asking many questions the whole day. I'm at the end...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is alright. You are using [`create_function()`](http://php.net/create_function) wrong. And subsequently the inner [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) doesn't work. The call to `data_uri()` happens before any regex-replacement takes place, hencewhy the undefined filename error.

Use a proper callback function:

```
$image_element = preg_replace_callback($pattern, "data_uri_callback", $image_element);
```

Then move your code into there:

```
function data_uri_callback($matchess) {
    return  $matchess[1] . data_uri($matchess[2]) . $matchess[3];
}
```